# Extend this basis to a basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{v_1, v_2,\dots , v_r\}$ be a set of vectors that spans a subspace $W$ of a vector space $V$. Prove that one can choose a
subset of these vectors that forms a basis for $W$, and that this basis can be extended to a basis for $V$. Demonstrate
this procedure on the vectors
$$(1,-1, 0, 0), (1, 0,-1, 0), (1, 0, 0,-1), (0, 1,-1, 0), (0, 1, 0,-1), (0, 0, 1,-1).$$

I removed the non-linearly independent vectors to get the basis (here written as a matrix):
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}.$$

However, I'm unsure how to extend this basis to a basis for $V$. In examples of this question online, I saw people use standard basis vectors to extend a basis. Do I do that here too? I'm confused because I believe that to find the dimensions we subtract the number of linearly-independent rows from the number of columns, here that would be $4 - 3$, which would be one dimension. This is obviously incorrect? I just don't know where I've gone wrong.

Comment: The middle line of your matrix is not one of the original vectors. I suppose that's a typo (the second $1$ should probably be $0$), but I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a basis for $W\subset\mathbb R^n$, you can extend it to a complete basis by finding the orthogonal complement of $W$. This is just the kernel of the matrix that has your basis vectors as its rows (which you’ve already written down). If you row-reduce this matrix, you get $\pmatrix{1&0&0&-1\\0&1&0&-1\\0&0&1&-1}$, from which you can read that the kernel is spanned by $(1,1,1,1)^T$.

Comment: So I choose a subset of linearly independent vectors, which is the basis of the subspace, and then by row reduction, I then get the extended basis?

Comment: @Maddie The idea here is that you decompose $V$ into $W\oplus W^\perp$. The row space of the matrix that has your basis as its rows is just $W$, and $W^\perp$, the orthogonal complement of $W$, is its null space. If you find a basis for the latter, you can extend your basis of $W$ with it to cover all of $V$.